# Why is `find -depth 1` so slow to list directories?

Tags: bash, performance, find, ls

I am listing directories in the current directory. Here are the two commands I am comparing:

```
ls -F | grep /

find . -type d -depth 1
```

The `ls` command is quasi instantaneous while the `find` command takes about 10 seconds. It feels like the `find` command is going through the content of each subdirectory while it does not seem to be required by the command.

What is `find . -type d -depth 1` doing to be so slow?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`-depth` does not stop at a single layer, you want `-maxdepth` for that.  Instead it tells `find` to process the directories contents before itself, i.e., a depth first search.

Try instead

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

it will find more than `ls -F | grep /` because it will also search "hidden" files, and for my example it was ever so slightly faster (0.091 seconds compared to 0.1).

Comment: FreeBSD and Darwin (macOS) include a `-depth n` primary in their implementations of the `free` command, and this is what the original poster was asking about. This is very different than the `-depth` primary (without a numeric argument). The `-depth n` option in question is testing depth in the directory tree, not causing a depth-first traversal (as does `-depth`) nor limiting the depth of descent (as does `-maxdepth n`).